# How to split multiple event handles in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, events, event-handling

Trying to figure out how to split the multiple events in a new line to make the code below cleaner.

```
$document.find('body').on(
    'click dblclick mousedown mousemove mouseout mouseover mouseup mousewheel keydown keypress keyup textInput touchcancel touchend touchmove touchstart blur change focus reset resize select scroll submit zoom',
    testConsole
);

function testConsole() {
    console.log(' test');
}
```

How can I make this code cleaner? Now I have a single line with all events which I want to handle, is it possible to put this in an array or something else to make it readable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create events with `array` and then `join` with `space`. check below code.

```js
var events = ['click', 'dblclick', 'mousedown', 'mousemove', 'mouseout', 'mouseover', 'mouseup', 'mousewheel', 'keydown', 'keypress', 'keyup', 'textInput', 'touchcancel', 'touchend', 'touchmove', 'touchstart', 'blur', 'change', 'focus', 'reset', 'resize', 'select', 'scroll', 'submit', 'zoom'];

events = events.join(" ");

$(document).find('body').on(events,testConsole);

function testConsole() {
    console.log(' test');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>dsdsdsd</body>
```